# count .plist dictionary items (iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

This is what the plist looks like raw:

```
{
    authorLastName = Doe;
    authorFirstName = Jane;
    imageFilePath = "NoImage.png";
    title = "Account Test 1";
    year = 2009;
},
{
    authorLastName = Doe;
    authorFirstName = John;
    imageFilePath = "NoImage.png";
    title = "Account Test 2";
    year = 2009;
},
```

I want to count the total items of a plist, and display them like: '4 Accounts'.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.plist"]; 
NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPlistPath]; 

NSArray *array = [[plistDict objectForKey:0]
                      sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; 

return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Accounts", [array count]]);
```

However, the result returns 0.  I want it to return the ammount of items in the dictionary.

Comment: Could 0 be a key? Isn't that objectAtIndex instead?

Comment: 0 can't be a key, so [plistDict objectForKey:0] is returning nil, which makes every message sent to it return nil.  So array is nil and [array count] is also nil.

Comment: Im trying to count the number of dictionary's under ROOT in a pList, for example, Under root, theres Item 1 and Item 2, under item one, there are 5 strings, FirstName, LastName, Nickname, Number, Image.  I just want to be able to count how many items there are, and display it in a Tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be an old OpenStep property list, which is supported as a read-only format.

Your code looks okay, except that `NSDictionary` only takes objects as keys, so "`[plistDict objectForKey:0]`" is not going to do what you expect. If you know the top level of your property list is an array, then assign it to an `NSArray`, rather than an `NSDictionary`. If it's actually a dictionary, use a string value for the key, rather than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is relaying the number of items in the first element of the dictionary, not the number of items of the dictionary itself. Instead what I think what you want is something like:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Accounts", [plistDict count]];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `[plistDict count]`?  Since you're passing in `0` as the key to the dictionary you won't get anything back since you can't use `nil` as a key or a value.